# Выбрать все ссылки на странице с помощью php

Tags: php

Всем привет. Есть DOM-дерево сайта, в нем есть ссылки на вк - `<a href="https://vk.com/*тут переменная*">Ссылка</a>`

Каким образом можно добавить в массив все ссылки на вк из DOM-дерева? т.е. мне нужно перебрать все ссылки в DOM и искать в них vk.com? Как правильнее это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите это сделать на Php

```
$url = "https://vk.com/?user=132&admin=1"; // пример

$arr = [];
if (preg_match('(https://vk.com/(.*))is',$url,$match)) {
    array_push($arr,$match[0]);
}
```

Соответственно, если у Вас ссылки будут находиться в массиве, то конструкцию if вставьте в цикл и вместо `$url` - `$example_array[$i]`